# When inheriting from a class, do the variables inherited get redefined by the inherited class through the parent class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have made two classes: *stack1* and *stack2* and defined my own stack operations of push(), pop(), isempty() and isfull(). I am trying to calculate a postfix expression from an input. I have made another class called *operation* that is a child of *stack1* and *stack2*, so I can access the functions of push(),pop(), etc.. within *operation*. I have a function within *operation* called operate() that does the dirty work on the stacks. Within this function I have a while loop that depends on *stack1* not being empty until the operation is complete; HOWEVER, when I step through this function top1, where *stack1* is pointing to, has been reset to 0. Is there a way to overcome this/am I doing something wrong? This is the first time I am using classes and such, so I am not sure of the ins and outs.

Here are the definitions of my classes:

```
class stack1 {
    private:
        int num1[SIZE/2];       int top1;
    public:
        void push1(int data)
        {
            if (is_full1());
            else
            {
                num1[top1] = data;
                top1++;
            }
        }
        int pop1(void)
        {
            if(is_empty1());
            else
            {
                top1--;
                return num1[top1];
            }
        }
        int is_empty1(void)
        {
            if(top1 == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        int is_full1(void)
        {
            if(top1 == SIZE)
            {
                return 1;
            }else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        stack1()
        {
            top1 = 0;           num1[SIZE/2] = {0};
        } };

class stack2 {
    private:
        int num2[SIZE/2];       int top2;   public:
        void push2(int data)
        {
            if (is_full2());
            else
            {
                num2[top2] = data;
                top2++;
            }
        }
        int pop2(void)
        {
            if(is_empty2());
            else
            {
                top2--;
            return num2[top2];
            }
        }
        int is_empty2(void)
        {
            if(top2 == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        int is_full2(void)
        {
            if(top2 == SIZE)
            {
                return 1;
            }else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        stack2()
        {
            top2 = 0;           num2[SIZE/2] = {0};
        } };

class operation: public stack2, public stack1 {
    private:
        int answer;
        int a;
        int b;
        int num_cnt;
        int ans;
        int from_st1;
        int from_st2;
    public:
        int c;
        int oper(void)
        {
            answer = 0;
            a = 0;
            b = 0;
            num_cnt = 0;
            ans = 0;
            c = 0;
            stack1 st1;
            stack2 st2;
            while(!st1.is_empty1())
            {
                from_st1 = st1.pop1();
                if(from_st1 == plus)
                {
                    st2.push2(from_st1);
                }else if(from_st1 == minus)
                {
                    st2.push2(from_st1);
                }else if(from_st1 == mult)
                {
                    st2.push2(from_st1);
                }else if (from_st1 == divide)
                {
                    st2.push2(from_st1);
                }else if(num_cnt == 1)
                {
                    num_cnt = 0;
                    if(ans == 0)
                    {
                        answer = b;
                        ans++;
                    }
                    a = from_st1;
                    from_st2 = st2.pop2();
                    if(from_st2 == plus)
                    {
                        c = a+answer;
                    }else if(from_st2 == minus)
                    {
                        c = a-answer;
                    }else if(from_st2 == mult)
                    {
                        c = a*answer;
                    }else if(from_st2 == divide)
                    {
                        c = a/answer;
                    }
                }else
                {
                    b = from_st1;
                }
                num_cnt++;
            }
        return c;
        }

        operation()
        {
            answer = 0;
            a = 0;
            b = 0;
            num_cnt = 0;
            ans = 0;
            from_st1 = 0;
            from_st2 = 0;
        } };
```

Comment: Why are you making local `st1` and `st2`?

Comment: Making `operation` a subclass of `stack1` and `stack2` appears to be a design error.  It doesn't do your code any good, since you are instantiating and using separate stack-objects anyway, it makes your `operation` object much bigger than it needs to be (since every `operation` object now includes a `stack1` objects and a `stack2` object that are never used for anything), and it doesn't make sense (since an operation is not a special kind of stack1 or a special kind of stack2, which is what subclassing those classes would imply)

Comment: " I have made another class called operation that is a child of stack1 and stack2, so I can access the functions of push(),pop(), etc.. within operation." That is wrong design! A operation is not any kind of stack! That methods of one class can operate with data from another class did not mean that you have to inherit. If this would be the case, all classes have to be inherited from each other. So start with a fresh design!

Comment: Another weirdness: `stack1` and `stack2` classes are almost identical, the only difference being the names of variables and methods. There is no reason to create two classes (i.e. two different _types_) with identical behaviour: possibly you need to create a _type_ and then 2 or more _instances_ of that type?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "problem" is with the line:

```
stack1 st1;
stack2 st2;
```

This will call the default constructor and set the value of the variables `top1` and `top2` as zero.
A workaround to this would be to initialise these variables with some positive non-zero value.

Hence the code would look something like(focusing only on the changed parts):

```
class stack1 {
    private:
        int num1[SIZE/2];       int top1;
    public:
        .....

        stack1()
        {
            top1 = 0;           num1[SIZE/2] = {0};
        } 
        stack1(int top1)
        {this.top1 = top1;}

};

class stack2 {
    private:
        int num2[SIZE/2];       int top2;   public:
    public:
        .....

        stack2()
        {
            top2 = 0;           num2[SIZE/2] = {0};
        } 

        stack2(int top2)
        {this.top2 = top2;}
};

class operation: public stack2, public stack1 {
        .....

    public:
        int c;
        int oper(void)
        {
            .....

            //just an example, can be declared explicitly as well
            stack1 st1(5);
            stack2 st2(7);
         .....
```

Also, I would advice you to make your code a bit more readable(for instance the presence of 3-liner `{}` in `if` cases spanning only a single line). It is just unnecessary consumption of space.

And finally, if the "redefinition" of parent class' variables means the variables re-asserting some value on being inherited, they don't, unless you specify explicitly(such as using a constructor in our case to assign different values to `top1` and `top2`). The inherited class will get a copy of the state of the parent class*.

*meaning they cannot be changed directly by the inherited class. For example if you would've done: `int top1=5;` initially then `top1` would've been 5 until it were to be redefined again somewhere(such as using a constructor)

Answer (score 0):

I take from the problem statement you are trying to build a basic calculator with four operators and need basic expression evaluation done using stack.
Say you have an expression: a+b-c*d/e
looks like this in stack: TOP e->/->d->*->c->-->b->+->a  EMPTY
And this track needs to be evaluated.

Based on these.. you may be looking for something like below:

```cpp
class stack {
    private:
        int num[SIZE];       
        int top;
    public:
        void push(int data)
        {
            if (is_full1());
            else
            {
                num[top] = data;
                top++;
            }
        }
        int pop(void)
        {
            if(is_empty());
            else
            {
                top--;
                return num[top];
            }
        }
        int is_empty(void)
        {
            if(top == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        int is_full(void)
        {
            if(top == SIZE)
            {
                return 1;
            }else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        stack()
        {
            top = 0;           num[SIZE] = {0};
        } 
};

class operation {
    private:
        int answer;
        int op1;
        int op;

    boolean isOperator(int val) {
        boolen retVal = false;;

        if (val == plus ||
            val == minus ||
            val == divide ||
            val == mult) {
                retVal = true;
            } 
        else {
            retVal = false;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
    public:
        int oper(stack st1)
        {
            int from_st1 = 0;
            while(!st1.is_empty())
            {
                from_st1 = st1.pop();
                if(isOperator(from_st1))
                {
                    op = from_st1;
                }
                else if(answer != 0)
                {
                    op1 = from_st1;
                    if(op == plus)
                    {
                        answer = op1 + answer;
                    }else if(op == minus)
                    {
                        answer = op1 - answer;
                    }else if(op == mult)
                    {
                        answer = op1 * answer;
                    }else if(op == divide)
                    {
                        answer = op1 / answer;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    answer = from_st1;
                }
            }
        return answer;
        }

        operation()
        {
            answer = 0;
            op1 = 0;
            op = 0;
        } 
};
```

Note: You can do all evaluation with one stack don't need two stacks. Your operands can not equal to integer values for +, -, * and / for this assignment. You have a valid expression input into stack in main() code.